# How to calculate statistical significance when a Levene significance value is not given?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, spss, levenes-test

I have performed an independent t-test on SPPS and retrieved these results:

[image: SPSS results]

[image: SPSS results 2]

No Levene significance value was given and so how would I know whether my results are significant?
Would I just divide the significance from the 2-tailed t-test by two?

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT: In my data set, it looks at the effect of variable(s) defined as 1 rather than 0. I have performed the Levene test on this exact data set before. In that case, it gave me a significance value. The only difference with these two tests was that in the successful test had two variables which were defined as 1. In the test above, only one variable was defined as 1. Is there an issue with this?

This is my original data:
[image: data]

Comment: Levene's test is a test for equality of variance.  So it is not applied when you test for equality of means using a t test.

Comment: Something appears to be wrong with either your data or SPSS syntax. There is a way to get SPSS to do the Levene's. Just poke around a bit.

Comment: @Michael Chernick some are trained to look at Levene's to decide which variance term to use. This is of course bankrupt as an approach and breaks the easy interpretability of p values. But it is done all the same.

Comment: Although I do not know what SPPS is the OP may have software different from SPSS although it is more likely a typo.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of style and preference. Generally the p value from the unequal variances equation is going to be more conservative. A Welch's t is generally 'safer' as you lose little power if the variances actually are equal and you avoid making a contingent decision in the calculation of your p value. Your specific example looks a bit rotten though. I recommend you recheck your data and syntax to be sure you're doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: In my data set, it looks at the effect of variable(s) defined as 1 rather than 0. I have performed the Levene test on this exact data set before. In that case, it gave me a significance value. The only difference with these two tests was that in the successful test had two variables which were defined as 1. In the test above, only one variable was defined as 1. Is there an issue with this?

Comment: Yes. With only a single value for the 1 group no variance estimate can be made for that group. Thus, no Levene's test or unequal variances test can occur either. More generally, making a generalization based on a single observation of the 1 group seems insanely questionable.

Comment: I was looking at the effect of colour on memory. So i defined, for example, the colour red to be 1 as I wanted to see the specific effect of red on memorability. The other colours were defined as 0.

Comment: Yeah, so if you only have one observation of the effect of red on memory, then you probably aren't that sure about how memorable it is.

Comment: I have inserted a screenshot of my data, hopefully this clarifies what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the methodology question, it appears that one of your groups simply has too few cases for the Levene test or unequal variance calculation.  This might be due to missing data.

Comment: In my data set, it looks at the effect of variable(s) defined as 1 rather than 0. I have performed the Levene test on this exact data set before. In that case, it gave me a significance value. The only difference with these two tests was that in the successful test had two variables which were defined as 1. In the test above, only one variable was defined as 1. Is there an issue with this?

Comment: I am lost.  If you want to send me the data and syntax, I will take a look (jkpeck@gmail.com)